# Python: Elif and Else not working

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I'm constructing an interactive timetable for terminal with Python, but at the end of my code where i have if, elif and else statements no matter what user input i give it keeps passing the if statement. Any Solutions would be greatly appreciated and Thank You for your time :)

```
while True:
    TimeTable()
    print "\nDo you wish to go again? "
    answer = raw_input()
    if answer == "Yes" or "yes":
        print " "
        continue
    elif answer == "No" or "no":
        print "Ok then"
        break
    else:
        print "Ok then"
        break
```

Comment: `answer == "Yes" or answer ==  "yes"`

do like this

Comment: or best to `answer.lower() == "yes"`

Comment: Try, `if answer == "Yes" or answer == "yes":` Do the same with `elif`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
answer == "Yes" or "yes"

# is the same as
(answer == "Yes") or "yes"
```

and is always True. You can solve your problem this way:

```
answer in ["Yes", "yes"]
```

Comment: or `answer.lower() == "yes"`

Comment: Since this question is a duplicate, it would be better to delete the answer to help the auto-deletion mechanics

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you so much! :)